# Accessing nested variables in Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, yaml, jinja2

Lets say I have this defined in my group_vars:

```
ucarp_data:
  - vhid: 6
    interface: eth0
    hosts:
      - 10.1.60.4
      - 10.1.60.5
    options: --shutdown --preempt

  - vhid: 9
    interface: eth0
    hosts:
      - 10.1.60.7
      - 10.1.60.8
    options: --shutdown --preempt
```

I want to check that the host I'm currently running against is in this `hosts:` array.

Something like:

```
- name: Check if ucarp_data contains this host
  assert:
    that: ansible_host in ucarp_data.hosts
```

But this returns `fatal: [test_machine]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible_host in ucarp_data.hosts' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible_host in ucarp_data.hosts): 'dict object' has no attribute 'hosts'"`

Any ideas?

Also I keep hitting these road blocks with Ansible and nested yaml variables... I can't seem to explore dynamically like if I was in a Jupyter Notebook I have tab completion on any Python object which helps immensely, any tips on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, given the list *ucarp_data*, the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: 10.1.60.5,10.1.60.7,10.1.60.9
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: inventory_hostname in ucarp_data|map(attribute='hosts')|flatten
        fail_msg: "[ERR] {{ inventory_hostname }} not in ucarp_data"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [10.1.60.5] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
ok: [10.1.60.7] => changed=false 
  msg: All assertions passed
fatal: [10.1.60.9]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: inventory_hostname in ucarp_data|map(attribute='hosts')|flatten
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: '[ERR] 10.1.60.9 not in ucarp_data'
```